# Why can't both require('foo') and ECMAScript exports be used in the same project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, import

Just getting up to speed with JavaScript and I'm encountering an issue I can't explain. I'm just trying to understand the different import options.

I have:

```
main.js
utils.js
package.json
```

utils.js

```
// this is simply an exemple from the node.js docs
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What is your name ? ", function(name) {
    rl.question("Where do you live ? ", function(country) {
        console.log(`${name}, is a citizen of ${country}`);
        rl.close();
    });
});
export {rl}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sandbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
   "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

main.js

```
import {rl} from './utils.js'

// do stuff with rl, but the import fails
```

With the code as per above, `require(...) is not defined`  if I try to run utils.js directly. I need to remove the export statement & "type":"module". If I rename utils.js to utils.mjs, then I get "require is not defined". So basically I cannot have both require(...) and use exports.

If I run main.js, then it says that utils.js doesn't provide an export named rl (but it does!).

Why is it that the "type":"module" & require(...) syntax can't coexist? If I'm using a package that already uses the require() syntax, then does that mean that the rest of my project cannot use the ECMAScript exports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it that the "type":"module" & require(...) syntax can't coexists?

[They can](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs). In an ESM module (JavaScript `import`/`export` syntax), you can import from a CJS module (the older CommonJS module system). You can also use [`createRequire`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequire_filename) if you need functionality that isn't otherwise available (like importing JSON).

> If I'm using a package that already uses the require() syntax, then does that mean that the rest of my project cannot use the ecmascript exports?

No, it's still possible, though life is much simpler if you convert fully to ESM (or don't use ESM at all — e.g., if you avoid using both at once). The `type` setting in the nearest `package.json` is what determines whether something being imported is using ESM or CJS by default. You could (for instance) have a directory for the old stuff with a minimal `package.json` in it that has `"type": "commonjs"` while your project's main `package.json` has `"type": "module"`.

```
project_root/
+ package.json w/"type": "module"
+ foo.js - ESM module
+ bar.js - ESM module
+ legacy/
  + package.json w/"type": "commonjs"
  + baz.js - CJS module
```

Alternatively, you can have `"type": "commonjs"` (or no `type` at all) in your main `package.json` and use the file extension `.mjs` on your ESM modules. (I'm not a fan of that, but Node.js supports it.)

More in the [Node.js ESM documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Comment: Oh I see. I hadn't quite understood the dynamics there and hadn't read all that way into node's docs. I had thought that was way more details than I was likely to need for an hello-world-ish program. From a Python background, so there's really only a single import mechanism and never ahd that much thought to put into it. Thanks for great explanation.

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions - My pleasure! If it's a Hello, World, just use `"type": "module"` and you're good -- you can import all the Node.js and npm packages with the new syntax. But yeah, in an existing project we're temporarily at the pain point of transitioning from the old mechanism to the new. :-)